# VisualStudio 2017 runs .exe when building on external console

Tags: c#, mono, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to learn some C# and am currently using the internal console for outputs, but when it comes to keyboard inputs,  I've read that it can not be done in the internal console on VS 2017 for Mac.

So I try to do it on external console, but all I get is this :

> bash -c 'clear; cd "/Users/gb/Projects/reTest/reTest/bin/Debug";
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.8.1/bin/mono32" 
>   --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:56795  "**/Users/gb/Projects/reTest/reTest/bin/Debug/reTest.exe**" ; echo $? >
>   /var/folders/s_/sljf42_d01bdxlb5s_rwgsj80000gn/T/tmp563f24ea.tmp;
>   echo; read -p "Press any key to continue..." -n1; exit'; exit

I guess the console tries to execute a .exe application which is not possible in this case !

It's a console project by the way... I haven't found any solution for that so far.

Thks.

Comment: That executable is a parameter to the `mono32` application. The mono compiler still creates `.exe` files no matter the platform.

Comment: Ok, well how to get the external console to work properly then ? So I can do my console.ReadLine() properly also.. ?

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: What isn't working is that the external console gives me this message, instead of executing the C# code.. at the end of this message I have ' Press any key to continue..." and it asks me for my password, then I have this : Found a swap file by the name "~/.bash_profile.swp"
          owned by: gb   dated: Mon Jul 18 15:11:07 2016
         file name: ~gb/.bash_profile
          modified: YES
         user name: gb   host name: pc38.home
        process ID: 63499
While opening file "/Users/gb/.bash_profile"
             dated: Mon Apr 23 19:33:32 2018
      NEWER than swap file!

Comment: If you're trying to learn C#, I recommend looking at .NET Core. It's cross-platform by design.

Comment: Firstly, it sounds like at some point you were editing your `.bash_profile` using Vim and it crashed or was killed and left a swap file behind. Secondly, are you sure your application is *not* running and waiting for input?

Comment: On each step I get nothing telling me that it's waiting for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further researches I found out that my bash was kind of corrupted somehow so I modified the **.bash_profile** file which had some extra inconvenient text..